# Current value of generator

Tags: python, generator

In Python I can build a generator like so:

```
def gen():
    x = range(0, 100)
    for i in x:
        yield i
```

I can now define an instance of the generator using:

```
a = gen()
```

And pull new values from the generator using

```
a.next()
```

But is there a way—`a.current()`—to get the current value of the generator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't such a method, and you cannot add attributes to a generator. A workaround would be to create an iterator object that wraps your generator, and contains a 'current' attribute. Taking it an extra step is to use it as a decorator on the generator.

Here's a utility decorator class which does that:

```
class with_current(object):

    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.__gen = generator()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.current = next(self.__gen)
        return self.current

    def __call__(self):
        return self
```

You can then use it like this:

```
@with_current
def gen():
    x=range(0,100)
    for i in x:
        yield i

a = gen()

print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(a.current)
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
1
```

Answer (score 6):

You set the value of a variable.

```
current_value = a.next()
```

then use current_value for all it's worth.
Python uses this often in for statements

```
a = xrange(10)
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

Here you are defining x as the current value of a.

Answer (score -2):

Using another global variable to store the current value might be feasible.

```
# Variable that store the current value of the generator
generator_current_val = None

def generator():
    global generator_current_val # to set the current value

    for i in range(10):
        generator_current_val = i
        yield i

a = generator()

print(next(a)) # 0
print(next(a)) # 1
print(next(a)) # 2
print(generator_current_val) # 2
print(next(a)) # 3
```

Comment: Globals are almost certainly a bad design.